# Is there a color replacement adjustment layer in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, layers, photoshop-effects

Is there a color replacement adjustment layer in Photoshop?

If not, why not? And can its effect be achieved using another method?

Comment: @Danielillo Why did you remove `Photoshop`?

Comment: Hi HappyFace, welcome to GDSE. When the users of this page read the questions, they first read the tags to know what the topic is. If there's an Adobe Photoshop's tag it's not necessary to repeat it in the question or in the title.

Comment: @Danielillo I have to disagree on this one, the first thing I'll read in the homepage is the question title. Also I don't think there's harm in mentioning what software the question is about to in the title.

Comment: Ok, to me it's redundant, anyway the edited questions can be rejected.

Comment: @Danielillo I don't see a reject option.

Comment: The answer to the question is no. As to why not, then I think that is a question only Adobe can really answer.  As for other methods, it would be better if you were to show some images to illustrate what you are actually trying to do, what you have tried, what has failed, etc.

Comment: @happyface - not reject, the option is to "rollback".

Comment: I think to give you a workaround, we need you to explain thoroughly why you need such a feature. Like what is the scenario here?

Comment: @BillyKerr My use case is pretty simple; I use simple color adjustments on rendered pictures. I like to store these adjustments somehow that I can easily apply them if I render the original picture with a different resolution.

Comment: @joonas See my comment earlier; Silly SE doesn't allow me to mention two people at once. :)

Comment: You can make a selection based on the same exact formula `Select > Color range`. You could perhaps use that and turn that into a Layer Mask. If you put the layer mask in a folder, you can put anything there and they get masked out... or after making the selection, just add any of the Adjustment layers and it automatically converts that selection into a Layer Mask. This obviously won't update itself if the image below changes, but is it close enough?

Comment: So, record the adjustments as an Action perhaps, and make sure you don't overwrite the original images, or alternatively, apply the adjustment on a duplicate of the image layer.  At least that way, you still have a copy that's unedited.

Answer (score 1):

Image > Adjustment > Replace Color allows you to save the change receipe as *.ATX file. You can load it when you apply Replace Color to a new image.

This is useful if the color range to be replaced has sharp borders in the image. There's no need to have the same geometric form nor size.

If you have a single layer image like this

[image]

and you want "Replace yellow with blue, do it equally in the mixes, too and do it without messing the mix in any way otherwise" you are out of luck. This system cannot decide right what was yellow's role in the mixes. You get something like this (dirty colors, grey):

[image]